# Why is 'i' an undeclared indentifier? (c++)

Tags: c++

[`image of code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqnNl.png)

I am able to use 'i' for course, but not for grade. I looked at other examples, and they do the same thing, allowing the 'i' to be in the grade section.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  float course1;
  float grade1;
  float totalhour =0;
  float points;
  float totalpoints =0;
  for(int i = 1; i <=4; ++i)
  cout << "Course " << i << "hours" ;
  cin >> course1;

  cout << "Grade for course " << i << endl;
  cin >> grade1;
}
```

ERROR:
use of undeclared identifier 'i'
cout << "Grade for course" << i << endl;
^

Comment: You can use `i` only in the body of the loop. `cout << "Course " << i << "hours" ;` is in the body of the loop but `cout << "Grade for course " << i << endl;` is outside the loop.

Comment: Without any brackets, the only thing the `for` loop iterates is the very next `cout << "Course "` statement. Then the loop ends and `i` goes out of scope.

Comment: *always use curly braces* especially when starting out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `i` is declared in the `for` loop and therefore it can be used only in the loop.

If you want to repeat multiple things, you should surround them by `{}`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  float course1;
  float grade1;
  float totalhour =0;
  float points;
  float totalpoints =0;
  for(int i = 1; i <=4; ++i) {
    cout << "Course " << i << "hours" ;
    cin >> course1;

    cout << "Grade for course " << i << endl;
    cin >> grade1;
  }
}
```

If you just want to use `i` after the loop, you should declare that before the loop.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  float course1;
  float grade1;
  float totalhour =0;
  float points;
  float totalpoints =0;
  int i;
  for(i = 1; i <=4; ++i)
  cout << "Course " << i << "hours" ;
  cin >> course1;

  cout << "Grade for course " << i << endl; // i will be 5 here
  cin >> grade1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` goes out of scope after the end for the `for` loop. [@Thomas Sablik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64840039/why-is-i-an-undeclared-indentifier-c/64840052?noredirect=1#comment114638951_64840039) [@dxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64840039/why-is-i-an-undeclared-indentifier-c/64840052?noredirect=1#comment114638957_64840039)

```
for (int i = 1; i <=4; ++i)
  cout << "Course " << i << "hours" ;
                                    ^ Loop ends here.

cout << "Grade for course " << i << endl;
                               ^ `i` no longer exists.
```

Comment: This answer does not explain what and why is needed to be done

Comment: @zolty13 OP did not ask for a fix, just "Why is 'i' an undeclared indentifier?"